# Obtaining Ids from two columns using awk

Tags: regex, awk

Below is my sample file (Two columns separated by tab):

```
A:Q08465 "\t" B-60323N

B-60323N "\t" A:P38806

A:P50947 "\t" B-60323N

A:P54784 "\t" A:P29469

A:P29469 "\t" A:P32833

A:P29469 "\t" A:P50874
```

I need to obtain the Id pairs represented by letter A only in a tab delimited format.

eg.

```
P54784 P29469

P29469 P32833

P29469 P50874
```

Any suggestions Please.

Comment: Sometime you have a "-" between the letter and the id. It is relevant ? By the way, why do you want to use awk ? What did you try ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"} sub(/A:/,"",$1) && sub(/A:/,"",$2)' file
P54784  P29469
P29469  P32833
P29469  P50874
```

Answer (score 3):

You can shorten the `awk` some:

```
awk -F":|\t" '$1$3=="AA" {print $2,$4}' file
P54784 P29469
P29469 P32833
P29469 P50874
```

Comment: That will put a single space between output fields, not a tab. Otherwise, nice golf stroke - +1! `-F'[:\t]'` would be preferable to `-F":|\t"` though for clarity and extensibility if your field separators ever had to include, say, a `|` or a few other characters.

Answer (score 2):

This ought to do it

```
$ awk -F'[:\t]' '$1 == "A" && $1 == $3 {print $2 "\t" $4}' data.txt 
P54784  P29469
P29469  P32833
P29469  P50874
```

Comment: That will put a single space between output fields, not a tab.

Answer (score 2):

Another variant:

```
awk -F"A:" 'NF==3{print $2$3}' data
P54784  P29469
P29469  P32833
P29469  P50874
```

tabs are still attached to the `$2` value in the output.

Answer (score 1):

like this :

```
cat file | awk -F'[:\t]' '$1 == "A" && $3 == "A" {print $2" "$4}'
```

outputs :

```
P54784 P29469
P29469 P32833
P29469 P50874
```

Comment: oh i didnt know the correct syntax to print, thats why, anyways my answer resembles that of yours

Comment: UUOC + unnecessary pipe + unnecessary hard-coding of the OFS + that will put a single space between output fields, not a tab.

Comment: i know, i will improve the answer, thanks for the input

Comment: You still have UUOC though. `file` should be an argument to `awk`

Comment: thats not a big problem , we can add the file name at the end of the awk as well. i just wrote it for clarity

Comment: If you want the file name at the start, you still don't need `cat` and a pipe, just use `<file awk 'script'` but in both cases you lose the access to FILENAME so you shouldn't do it, you should always just let awk open the file unless you NEED piped input for some reason. You still have the other issues anyway and once you fix those you'll have the same script as @veryhungrymike.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{if ($1 ~ /A/ && $2 ~ /A/) {sub(/A./,"",$1);sub(/A./,"",$2); print $1,$2;}}' input.txt
```

Comment: awk _assumes_ `if (test) { }`, so you can just write `awk '$1 ~ /A/ && $2 ~ /A/ {sub(/A./,"",$1);sub(/A./,"",$2); print $1,$2;}' input.txt`

Comment: That will put a single space between output fields, not a tab. Also because it's using the metacharacter `.` rather than `:` in the RE it'll produce false positives if the text after the `:` starts with an A, for example, instead of a P or a Q or a number.

Comment: I interpreted the input this way "There's an `A` followed by `:` or maybe `-` but nothing else" thus decided to use `.`

Comment: Understood but then you open yourself up to the problem I described. If you used `[-:]` or `[^[:alnum:]]` or similar instead of `.` you'd solve the problem you identified without creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your data set, you could simply do:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\t"}gsub(/A:/,"")==2' file
P54784  P29469
P29469  P32833
P29469  P50874
```

`gsub` function returns the number of substitutions made. Since you intend to print id pairs that are represented by letter `A` we use that for substitution. When the return value matches our check of `==2` then it forms a true statement (for lines that contains id pairs with `A` which automatically triggers a default print action.

Using the `gsub` function also allows us to remove them as desired seeing your output.

Comment: +1 for code golf, but -0.5 for readability. The time saved by typing fewer characters is much less than the time it would take to figure out your own intentions six months later.

Comment: Thanks @veryhungrymike. I do appreciate your up-vote and feedback. I went with idiomatic way not realizing the fact it would get close to golfing. I have added some explanation for OP and future readers.